# I'm having this error in ms access query input must contain at least one table or query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-insert, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to insert single values from other tables but getting this error. If you know that how to fix then please fix mine code ...

Check this:

```
INSERT INTO Library_Records_DB(Book_Name, Student_Roll_Num, Student_Name, Student_Department, Lending_Date)
values
(
"English", 
747, 
(select Full_Name from GCUF_Students_DB_Morning where Roll_Num=747), 
(select Department from GCUF_Students_DB_Morning where Roll_Num=747), 
"01-jan-2020"
)
```

Comment: Are you really storing dates as text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try something like:

```
INSERT INTO Library_Records_DB
    (Book_Name, Student_Roll_Num, Student_Name, Student_Department, Lending_Date)
select "English", Roll_Num, Full_Name, Department, "01-jan-2020"
from GCUF_Students_DB_Morning
where Roll_Num=747
```

(But I don't know your data. Will the select return one row?)